# Why apache mod_rewrite doesn't work with "'/" but with underscore yes?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have classic link as

```
www.hello.it/test.php?id=1
```

and I want it becomes

```
www.hello.it/test/1
```

I have these rules:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^test/([0-9]+)/?$ test.php?id=$1 [L]
```

in the browser with www.hello.it/test/1 returns me "Not found"
but if I change the second rule with '_' or '-' in place of "/" it works.

```
RewriteRule ^test_([0-9]+)/?$ test.php?id=$1 [L]
```

My question is why? I tried to escape it but it doesn't work anyway.

Any help would be approciated

Comment: Are there any other rules?

Comment: No, only these two rules

Comment: Try placing `Options -MultiViews` on top of your .htaccess.

Comment: Thanks! It works! :)

Comment: Saw this is still listed as 'unanswered': to close this question, one of you'd have to provide the answer as actual answer and @Pierminator would then have to accept it.